# Rally: Reopened Defects Report

Tags: rally

I am working on creating a report which contains "Defect ID, Defect Name, Creation Date and current state" of the reopened defects. This means all defects that had the state of reopened at some point during the defect cycle, the only way to find if the defect has ever been in reopened state is from the defects revision history.

There isn't any report in Rally that currently supports this. If anyone can help us on how to create one or give us an similar example that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [Defects by Closer App](http://developer.rallydev.com/help/defects-closer-app) as a starting point.  It performs a similar function by searching through the revision history for who closed a defect.  You should be able to modify is slightly to search the revision text for "OPENED DATE changed" rather than "CLOSED DATE added":

```
for (j = 0; j < defect.RevisionHistory.Revisions.length; j++) {
    var revision = defect.RevisionHistory.Revisions[j];
    if (revision.Description.search("OPENED DATE changed") !== -1) {
        //Found a reopened defect
    }
}
```

For reference here is an example revision history entry from a reopened defect:

OPENED DATE changed from [Fri Jan 27 07:50:36 EST 2012] to [Fri Jan 27 07:51:00 EST 2012], STATE changed from [Closed] to [Open], CLOSED DATE removed [Fri Jan 27 07:50:50 EST 2012]

For more information on writing apps check out the [App SDK](http://developer.rallydev.com/help/app-sdk) documentation on [Rally's Developer Portal](http://developer.rallydev.com).

**NOTE**: You can view the source code for Defects by Closer app [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RallyApps/app-catalog/master/src/legacy/DefectsByCloserApp.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you hit the new Lookback API (unreleased when Kyle first answered, now in open preview), you can query directly for snapshots (revisions) where the State was ever set to a value "Reopened". Alternatively, you can look for any instance where OpenedDate changed by querying for `"_PreviousValues.OpenedDate": {$exists: true}`.

You can find information on the LBAPI [here](https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/doc/). There is support for querying it in the App SDK 2.0's SnapshotStore. Note that SDK 2.0p6 (releasing soon) has some improvements.